# Check if SPWorkflow is running

Tags: workflow

I have a `SPWorkflow` object and I want to check if this workflow is running. It's a Sandbox solution so I don't have access to `SPWorkflow.SPWorkflowStatus`.

I have tried the following:

```
if (workflow.InternalState != SPWorkflowState.Running)
{
     // the workflow is not running
}
```

but what I get in `workflow.InternalState` is a list of `SPWorkflowState` enum values: "Running" and "NotStarted". This doesn't make any sense to me.

It should be a pretty simple thing but just can't get it to work.

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The workflow is acting on an item (sometimes called a context item) -- you can get its GUID from `workflow.ItemGuid`.  Then, you can check the workflow status from one of its fields, as [eirikb](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/627/eirikb) said.

Once you have the `SPListItem`, you can then query its properties to get the workflow status number.

[Here](http://sharepointdevelopertopics.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-check-workflow-status.html) is a blog post about this, but for completeness, here's some untested, on-the-fly code for you:

```
var parentList = workflow.ParentList;
var listItem = parentList.GetItemByUniqueId(workflow.ItemGuid);
var workflowStatus = listItem[list.WorkflowAssociations[workflow.AssociationId].Name]);
```

`workflowStatus` should be a positive `int` -- it's an enumeration value whose friendly name is outlined on the like [eirikb](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/627/eirikb) noted.  Again, for completeness, [here](http://dzeee.net/sharepoint/post/2010/04/06/Workflow-status-codes-%28used-for-view-filter%29.aspx) it is.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a column on your list with the same name as the workflow association.
This column should contain a number which represents a [status of your workflow](http://dzeee.net/sharepoint/post/2010/04/06/Workflow-status-codes-%28used-for-view-filter%29.aspx). So if this column is set to `2` then your workflow is running.

Comment: As it's a sandbox solution I don't have access to `SPWorkflowStatus` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx)

Comment: The column I'm talking about is on the item, you should have access to it.

Comment: If the item is the workflow I can't see that value on the item.